# React native nested object loop with promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, es6-promise

I have a JSON object as follows

```
var allUsers = {
        "student_a":{
            id:1,
            full_name:"ABC",
            address:"xyz",
            image:"image url"
        },
        "student_b":{
            id:2,
            full_name:"DEF",
            address:"",
            image:"image url"
        },
         "student_c":{
            id:3,
            full_name:"",
            address:"",
            image:""
        }
    }
```

In the above JSON I need to figure out how many empty fields are there in each student.

I am using the following code

```
_submitInfo(allUsers) {
            var empty_fields = Object.entries(allUsers).map(([key, value]) => {
                return this._validateStudent(value)
            })
            alert(JSON.stringify(empty_fields))      
        }

_validateStudent(studentInfo) {   
            empty = 0;
            Object.entries(studentInfo).map(([key, value]) => {
                if (value == "") {
                    empty++
                }
            })
            return empty
        }
```

But the output I get is `[0,0,0]` the desired output is `[0,1,3]`.
I think promises will solve the issue but I am unaware of how will I use them in this nested case.

Comment: your code returns `[0, 1, 3]`  check again

Comment: No it dose not I  just rechecked

Comment: check here [link Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/srthapa927/u5h4qdmj/1/)

Answer (score 1):

As you want to use promises with above problem I updated your code with promises, just take a look.

```js
    var allUsers = {
        "student_a": {
            id: 1,
            full_name: "ABC",
            address: "xyz",
            image: "image url"
        },
        "student_b": {
            id: 2,
            full_name: "DEF",
            address: "",
            image: "image url"
        },
        "student_c": {
            id: 3,
            full_name: "",
            address: "",
            image: ""
        }
    }

check(allUsers);
    function check() {
        const promiseContainer = [];
        Object.entries(allUsers).map(([key, value]) => {
            promiseContainer.push(_validateStudent(value));
        });

        function _validateStudent(studentInfo) {
            let empty = 0;
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                Object.entries(studentInfo).map(([key, value]) => {
                    if (value == "") {
                        empty++
                    }
                })
                resolve(empty);
            });
        }

        Promise.all(promiseContainer).then((count) => { console.log(count) });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var allUsers = {
    "student_a":{
        id:1,
        full_name:"ABC",
        address:"xyz",
        image:"image url"
    },
    "student_b":{
        id:2,
        full_name:"DEF",
        address:"",
        image:"image url"
    },
     "student_c":{
        id:3,
        full_name:"",
        address:"",
        image:""
    }
}


var result = Object.keys(allUsers).map(student => Object.values(allUsers[student]).reduce((n, v) => {
    if(!v.toString().length) n += 1;
    return n
},0))
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perfect the below code is working

```
var result = Object.keys(allUsers).map(student => Object.values(allUsers[student]).reduce((n, v) => {
    if(!v.toString().length) n += 1;
    return n
},0))
```

but there is more issue, what if the JSON is as follows

```
var allUsers = {
        "student_a":{
            id:1,
            full_name:"ABC",
            address:"xyz",
            email:"a@a.com",
            number:"1234567890",
            image:"image url"
        },
        "student_b":{
            id:2,
            full_name:"DEF",
            address:"",
            email:"random value",
            number:"000",
            image:"image url"
        },
         "student_c":{
            id:3,
            full_name:"",
            address:"",
            email:"",
            number:"",
            image:""
        }
    }
```

and there is an email and phone number and if either invalid I consider it as blank.
So in the above JSON the output should be [0,3,5] 
3 empty fields for student_b as email and phone number is invalid.
Where do it put this condition ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const allUsers= {
    "student_a":{
        id:1,
        full_name:"ABC",
        address:"xyz",
        image:"image url"
    },
    "student_b":{
        id:2,
        full_name:"DEF",
        address:"",
        image:"image url"
    },
     "student_c":{
        id:3,
        full_name:"",
        address:"",
        image:""
    }
};

let arr=[];    
Object.entries(allUsers).map(([key,val]) => {
  x= Object.values(val).reduce((count, cur) => {
   if(cur == ""){
   return ++count;
   }
   return count;
  },0)
 arr.push(x);
});
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be working properly.

```
 var data = {
        "student_a":{
            id:1,
            full_name:"ABC",
            address:"xyz",
            image:"image url"
        },
        "student_b":{
            id:2,
            full_name:"DEF",
            address:"",
            image:"image url"
        },
         "student_c":{
            id:3,
            full_name:"",
            address:"",
            image:""
        }


    }


     let output =[]
     for (let value of Object.values(data)) {

       var test = Object.values(value)
       var lucky = test.filter(function(number) {
      return number == "";
    });

       output.push(lucky.length)

    }


    console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

For this format

```
var allUsers = {
    "student_a":{
        id:1,
        full_name:"ABC",
        address:"xyz",
        email:"a@a.com",
        number:"1234567890",
        image:"image url"
    },
    "student_b":{
        id:2,
        full_name:"DEF",
        address:"",
        email:"random value",
        number:"000",
        image:"image url"
    },
     "student_c":{
        id:3,
        full_name:"",
        address:"",
        email:"",
        number:"",
        image:""
    }
}
```

to get your output `[0,3,5]`

do this:

```
Object.keys(allUsers).map(obj => allUsers[obj]).map(item => { 
   item.email = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/.test(item.email) ? item.email : ""; // valid email or ""
   item.number = item.number ? item.number.match(/\d/g).length ===10 ? item.number : "" : item.number;  //valid number or ""
   return item; 
}).map(item => Object.values(item).filter(innerItem => innerItem === "").length);
```

this will print `[0, 3, 5]`

[live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-lahxb8)